# Series solution to Legendre equation: QM interpretation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hydrogen

I can't figure out how Legendre polynomials can be interpreted to give the angular part of the wavefunction of hydrogen orbitals. The recurrence relationship is $a_{n+2} = $$\frac{(n-l)(n+l+1)}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$a_{n}$, so a series exists for $0 < n < l$, and there are two of them, odd and even, which form the general solution.

If we interpret $l$ as the orbital angular momentum and $n$ as the principal quantum number, n should be $≥ l$, or alternatively $0 ≤ l ≤ n$. My primary background is in chemistry, and I don't see how chemistry fits the maths.

Any suggestions that would clean up my understanding would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: In addition to the answer below, you may want to check your recurrence relation, because it should give $0$ for at some point. The associated Legendre polynomials $P_l^m(x)$ are related to the derivatives of Legendre polynomials $P_l(x)$ as $$P_l^m(x) = (-1)^m \left(1- x^2 \right)^{m/2} \frac{d^m}{dx^m}P_l(x)$$But the $P_l(x)$ are polynomials of order l, $$P_l(x) = \frac{(-1)^l}{2^l \;l!} \frac{d^l}{dx^l} \left(1- x^2 \right)^l$$ and for $m>l$ their derivatives vanish. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AssociatedLegendrePolynomial.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendrePolynomial.html

Comment: @udrv thank you! Yes, I made a mistake! I think it's all much clearer to me now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $n$ of your recursion relation is not related
the principal quantum number.  It is a dummy variable and a bad coincidence that the recursion uses $n$ rather than - say - $s$ or $k$.

---

In a central potential, the separation of variable techniques leads to an angular equation that is just the Legendre differential equation in the polar variable.  Thus the Legendre polynomials - or more generally the spherical harmonics when one includes the azimuthal dependence - will always occurs as a solution to the angular part irrespective of the details of the central potential, and thus irrespective if the details of the energies.  Examples of potentials where spherical harmonics occur include the Coulomb potential (hydrogen case for instance), the 3d harmonic oscillator, the particle in a spherical well.  Spherical harmonics also occur in plane wave expansion.

The angular differential equation for the polar part is in fact the associated Legendre equation, and it collapses to the "simple" Legendre equation only for $m=0$.  For $m\ne 0$ the solutions are associated Legendre polynomials.

Specifically $Y_{\ell,m}(\theta,\phi)$ is proportional to $P_\ell^{\vert m\vert}(\cos\theta)e^{-im\phi}$ where $P_\ell^k$ is an associated Legendre.

Thus in general there is no universal connection between the possible values of $\ell$ and the principal quantum number.  The Coulomb and harmonic potential stand out because of additional degeneracies that link these two quantum numbers (in different ways for the two cases.)

In hydrogen, the possible values of $\ell$ go from $0$ to $n-1$, where $n$ is the principal quantum number.  In 3d oscillator, they go from $n$ down to $0$ or $1$ in steps of $2$, i.e. $n,n-2,n-4....$ down to $0$ or $1$.

In these cases where there are degeneracies, it is possible to have a state with given energy that is a linear combination of $\ell$ states.  However, in general, because the angular equation is solved independently of the radial equation, the solutions are usually found for individual $\ell$ and then  combined if the potential allows such combinations.

Comment: thank you! So what is then the connection between spherical harmonics as the angular part of Q.M. orbitals and Legendre polynomials? Because Legendre polynomials do correspond to each $Y_{l, m_l = 0}$ (after expressing them as function of $cos\theta$ and multiplying by a complex exponential).

Comment: @Alex : does the edit work for you?

Comment: @Alex updated yet to explicitly answer your question.

Comment: thanks! But I still don't understand: (1) When we derive the angular differential equation form the eigenvalue equation for the Hamiltonian, we already specify the value of $l$, so I would think that the solution for a given $l$ should be the complete series, not an individual term $P_\ell^{\vert m\vert}(\cos\theta)e^{-im\phi}$. (2) Could you please explain what those additional degeneracies, linking $n$ and $l$, are or suggest any texts that explain them? Really, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Alex : just added stuff.  The issue of degeneracies is everywhere the Coulomb problem and the 3d oscillator is treated.

Comment: Thank you very much! I also made a mistake in my calculation and it all now agrees with the quoted series.